# ¿Como clonar un Array en otro nuevo?

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito pasar información de un `array` a otro, en definitiva, quiero copiar los valores de `arrayPrimero` a `arraySegundo`, pero que los valores se puedan cambiar sin modificar el otro, y no sé cómo hacer, me sale error.

Código:

```
var arrayPrimero=[2,3,4,5]
var arraySegundo=[]
[2, 3, 4, 5] = []
```

Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

¿Es posible solucionar esto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utiliza [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice).

```js
var arrayPrimero = [2,3,4,5]
var arraySegundo = arrayPrimero.slice();

arrayPrimero[1] = 123;

console.log(arrayPrimero);
console.log(arraySegundo);
```

Tambien puedes usar `var arraySegundo= [].concat(arrayPrimero);` pero es una forma un poco menos eficiente.

Aqui te dejo una benchmark que muestra una comparativa de performance entre las diferentes formas de clonar un arreglo en javascript (hay varias formas) http://jsben.ch/#/wQ9RU

De las formas nativas, `slice` es la mas performante. Pero esto puede ahora o en el futuro variar incluso entre navegadores.

NOTA: Vale aclarar que el error que recibes es por que en javascript (desde ECMAScript 2015) existe el **deescructurado de arrays** el cual permite expandir un array en diferentes variables. Pero esto no esta relacionado con lo que intentas hacer sino con la syntaxis que utilizaste.

```js
// se requiere navegador compatible. Probado con Chrome 53
var [uno, dos, tres] = [1,2,3];
console.log(uno,dos,tres);
```

Comment: +1 - Te iba decir que con `arrayPrimero.concat();` es también posible... no conocia `http://jsben.ch`... guapo guapo

Comment: Sí, eso era justo lo que necesitaba... En ese test me dice que `slice` es el más rápido... Cierto lo del título, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción para agregar los elementos de un arreglo a otro arreglo puede ser:

```js
// Variables.
var arrayPrimero = [2,3,4,5];
var arraySegundo = [];

// Recorrer los elementos del arreglo "arrayPrimero"
// para agregarlos al arreglo "arraySegundo".
for (var i = 0; i < arrayPrimero.length; i++) {
   arraySegundo.push(arrayPrimero[i]);
}

// Imprimir los resultados en la consola.
console.log(arraySegundo);
```

```html
<i>Presiona la tecla F12 y mira la pestaña "Console" de tu navegador para verlos resultados.</i>
```

Para cambiar el valor de un elemento en el arreglo, puedes usar un ejemplo similar al siguiente:

```
var nuevo_valor = 10;
var posicion = 1;

// Cambiar el valor que está en la posición "1".
arraySegundo[posicion] = nuevo_valor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Con EcmaScript 2015 (ES6) puedes usar el spread operator.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const copyArr = [...arr];

console.log(copyArr); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Copiando de arraySegundo hacia arrayPrimero: Convertirmos el array en una cadena y luego parseamos esta cadena a JSON (recuerda que el Array es una estructura de datos compatible con JSON).

```
  var arrayPrimero = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arraySegundo));
```